# Is realizing the goal the same thing as achieving the goal?

Tags: word-meaning

He realized the goal.
Does it mean he understood the goal or he fulfilled the goal? Could you help me clarify it? Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

This usage of "realize" takes the meaning of the root word "real" literally. It means "make it real." And yes, it's a synonym for "achieved" in this context.

Note that this usage of "realize" is transitive, while the meaning of realize that is a synonym for "to understand" is intransitive.

Comment: Realise as *understand* is transitive too... *he realised his mistake*.